# Standard Normal Expectation

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

Let $Φ$ be the CDF of $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Find $E[ZΦ(Z)]$ and $E[Z^2\cdot Φ(Z)]$

Expectation for a continuous RV is the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ of xf(x)dx. How do I apply that here?

Note: $\Phi$ is the CDF, not PDF.

Comment: Yes and it looked right to me. I wouldn't know any better?

Comment: How do you explain the first "(Change of order of integration)" step then?

Comment: I thought that property was allowed if you changed the bounds too, as he did.

Comment: If it's not right and can be "shortened considerably", how would you do it?

Comment: Do you think that seeing that the OP accepted rapidly a wrong answer and is now circling the wagons around it like you do is an incentive to post another, correct, answer? It is not. Note also that your question has no personal input. Why?

Comment: There. Unaccepted? Happy?

Comment: If I had any clue how to do the problem I wouldn't be here asking it. My input is what I wrote about expectation of a continuous rv. Sorry we can't all be as good at this as you.

Comment: "Sorry we can't all be as good at this as you" Nice diversion, quite offtopic. If you have a question without context, this site is not the one to post it on (there are tons of others). Note that, in the world I live in, inexperienced people who have a math question, usually have tons of things to say about it (not all pertinent, of course, but why bother?). How come you are staying completely mute about your own question?

Comment: Why say stuff that would end up confusing more people? I came here for help, not for a lecture or for you to go around downvoting posts.

Comment: "Why say stuff that would end up confusing more people?" Wow. OK, at this point I can only suggest that you read any kind of howtoask page on this site (if you do that, you should realize how far your mindset is from the way the site is functioning).

Comment: OK, so it seems I lost my time here. Too bad. Best of luck with your next no-context questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**NOTE**: $\phi(x)$ represents Gaussian cdf , and $\psi(x)$ represents Gaussian pdf

$E[Z\phi(Z)]$

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z}{z\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dxdz}$

(Change of order of integration)

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x}{z\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dzdx}$

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot(\int_{-\infty}^{x}z{\cdot}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz)dx}$

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot(-\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2}))dx}$

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2)dx}$

$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$

$E[Z^2\phi(Z)]$

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z}{z^2\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dxdz}$
$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x}{z^2\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dzdx}$

(Change of order of integration)

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot(
\int_{-\infty}^{x}z^2{\cdot}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2}
)dz)dx}$

(Integrate by parts)

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot(
z\cdot\int z{\cdot}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz-\int \frac{d}{dz}z{\cdot}(\int z\cdot\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz)dz
)dx}$

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot(
x{\cdot}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})-\int_{-\infty}^{x} -\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz)
)dx}$

($\phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz$)

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot(
x{\cdot}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})+\sqrt{2\pi}\phi(x))
)dx}$

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}
x{\cdot}\exp(-x^2)dx+\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\cdot\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})
dx}$

(Odd function integrates to zero)

$=0+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})
dx$

Let $I=\int\phi(x)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})
dx$

(Integrate by parts)

$I=\phi(x)\cdot\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})
dx-\int (\frac{d}{dx}\phi(x))(\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})
dx)dx$

($\phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz$)

$=\phi(x)\cdot\phi(x)-\int (\frac{d}{dx}\phi(x))(\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})
dx)dx$

($\frac{d}{dx}\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz$)

$=\phi^2(x)-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})
\cdot\phi(x)dx$

$=\phi^2(x)-I$

So, $I=\frac{\phi^2(x)}{2}$

So, $E[Z^2\phi(Z)]=\frac{\phi^2(\infty)-\phi^2(-\infty)}{2}=\frac{1-0}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: So then what would be $E[Z*\psi(Z)]$ and $E[Z^2*\psi(Z)]$? That's really what the problem is asking.

Comment: @user395073 thats what I have calculated. this is a very lengthy answer. i hope you understand.

Comment: Ah I see you switched the symbols now. I understand but could never have come up with that myself. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: 1. This can be shortened considerably. 2. Nobody, and I mean *nobody*, uses the symbol $\psi$ to denote the gaussian CDF $\Phi$. 3. Why not allow the OP to add what they tried to solve this question, as the site requires, before answering?

Comment: @Did happy now?

Comment: This is even worse. Why not get minimally informed about the conventions of the field and follow them?

Comment: @Did I am VERY VERY SORRY that I did not know how YOU represent it. But from where I come, they use 'F' and 'f' (or 'P') for cdf and pdf respectively BY CONVENTION.

Comment: For the standard normal random variable? Sorry but I doubt that. (Unrelated: You might want to stop the words in capitals, they just make you look childish.)

Comment: By the way, already the first step of your answer is wrong. For a given function $h$, it is not true in general that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^zh(x,z)dx\right) dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^xh(x,z)dz\right) dx$$

Comment: @Meet Taraviya I put +1 immediately but it doesn't show because I don't have enough points yet.

Comment: @Did Don't attack him for trying to be helpful.

Comment: @user395073 What? Signalling wrong answers is the best service there is on a mathematical site. Equating this with "attacking" a user shows that one fails to understand the goal of the site (which is called **math**.se, remember?).

Comment: @Did You can be nice about it though...

Comment: Being precise and to the point is being nice, especially to point mistakes in some posted accepted answers. Refusing to acknowledge the mathematical errors in one's own answers is a plague. Agreed? (Addition: Accepting answers one did not even check is making the site dysfunctional. Agreed too?)

Comment: Actually I don't agree. If I were able to check and know that everything was right or not, I wouldn't have had to post this question.

Comment: @user395073 Again? So, you are saying that you were not able to check the validity of this answer? Seems like an excellent reason to not accept it until more detailed explanations are provided, no? You are really using the site backwards...

Comment: @Meet Taraviya Do you have another way like he said? I'm not going to bash what you say.

Comment: @Did sorry if you got offended. but you started with the harsh language. You could have been more supportive. After all eerybody makes mistakes :)  .

Comment: Suuure. What about correcting the mathematics?

Comment: @Did AFAIK there is no mistake in there. otherwise you are welcome too edit my answer

Comment: "AFAIK there is no mistake in there" This is truly excellent... Your (first) basic, massive, blunder was signaled in a comment a day ago.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. You are allowed to change order of integration when you change the bounds in accordance with the reversal.

Comment: "I still don't understand the problem" Obviously you do not. This is disquieting.

Comment: Another wrong step: a bit further it is stated that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\cdot(-\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2}))dx}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2)dx}$$ You think so?